# JQGrid with similar grids is there a way to reuse your javascript code rather then setting up every option again?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

When I am using multiple grids on the same page, or over my entire website, is there any way to abstract out the setup of common grid components? Ex the colModel section, or other components that would be the same between two grids, while giving me the option to make each grid unique, Ex in name, caption, etc.

Basically what this comes down to is I want to avoid the wall of text that comes with the setup of multiple grids that are highly similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve some of what I was looking for.

I was able to take the largest chunk of repeated code, the colModel:[..] and turn that into a variable and then call on it.

Ex

```
var colModelForReuse = [{name: 'exName', index: 'exIndex' ..... }, 
                        {.......................................}];
```

and then later in my Grid setup

```
colNames: [ 'exName', .....],
colModel: colModelForReuse,
pager: pagerName,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create a function that creates your actual grid, and then pass options to it to control the aspects that are different between each grid. A nice way to pass the arguments is to use [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), which allows you to easily provide default argument values.

For example:

```
function myFunction(options) {
    options = jQuery.extend(
        {
            myOption1:         'Default Vaule',
            myOption2:         'Default Vaule',
        },
        options || {});
    ...
}
```